# How to display xml string in a Label?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

I am trying to get my HTML method below, to encode the string and display it on label, but I keep getting a blank page, on the client-side.

I have checked the viewsource and it shows no HTML output their also.

```
public partial class About : Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e, string data)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string a = createXMLPub(data);
            // Label1.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(a);
            Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(a);
        }
    }

public static string createXMLPub(string data )
{
    XElement xeRoot = new XElement("pub");
    XElement xeName = new XElement("name", "###");
    xeRoot.Add(xeName);
    XElement xeCategory = new XElement("category", "#####");
    xeRoot.Add(xeCategory);
    XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(xeRoot);
    data = xDoc.ToString();
    return data;

}
```

HTML

```
 <asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
 </asp:Content>
```

Please advice, to where I may be going wrong with this code. Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? What happens when just placing a text in the label?

Comment: It's not elegant to have a parameter for nothing in your function, you should consider removing it.

Comment: I have tried to debug the page_load method, but it does not show the local variable window, hence I am assuming, "window" is a client-side variable, so it won't be available from server-side code.I have tested the label control with text; `Label1.Text = "createXMLPub";`. I have checked the label property and its set to visible. Please advice further, please. Thank you for your help and time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your `Page_Load` isn't fired - re: the extra `string data` param [doesn't match the signature for the event delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.100).aspx)

So:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string a = createXMLPub();
            Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(a);
        }
    }

    public static string createXMLPub()
    {
        XElement xeRoot = new XElement("pub");
        XElement xeName = new XElement("name", "###");
        xeRoot.Add(xeName);
        XElement xeCategory = new XElement("category", "#####");
        xeRoot.Add(xeCategory);
        XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(xeRoot);

        return xDoc.ToString();
    }
```

Hth...

Comment: Thank you, this has a been great help.  Thank you very much for amending my method and explaining the logic behind it as well.